# difference between &ptr.member and &(ptr.member)

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, struct

I'm writing a c program and I'm not too certain about how to write data to the particular members of a struct. I'm using a struct pointer that gets allocated memory using realloc() and accessing that data similar to an array. The array is dynamically resized each time an element is added.

My question is when writing data to an array index what is the correct way to do this?

```
struct s{...some data members...}
struct s *s_array = NULL;

//allocate memory at some point using realloc()

printf("enter some data: ");
scanf("%d", &s[index].data_member);
```

OR

```
scanf("%d", &(s[index].data_member));
```

Comment: Always good to keep [**C Operator Precedence**](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence) handy (or whatever link you like)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The array index operator `[]` and the member access operator `.` both have higher precedence than the address-of operator `&`.

So `&s[index].data_member` is valid to get the address of a member of an array element.  The parenthesis in `&(s[index].data_member)` are redundant and not needed.

Comment: ... so to directly answer the OP's question, the two alternatives presented in the question are equivalent.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Right.  I've added that to be more clear.

Comment: @NTesfai Glad I could help.  Feel free to [accept this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) if you found it useful.